# Why doesn't Bendy Bones' Easing property work in pose mode?

Tags: armature, bones, pose-mode

i was just familiarizing myself with the new Bendy Bones to plan a rig when i ran into this problem. ...gif below. it's unlikely that i caused it, cuz what you see is a really simple setup and the problem persisted every time i recreated the setup: add a bendy bone, add a mesh, weight. it's disappointing - i could really use that property.

edit: what i mean is that it's not affecting the mesh like Curve XY Offsets or Scale :]

however, you can see on this youtube video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nQCo2AGRT6o, it actually works as it's supposed to. he's using 2.77.1 and i'm using 2.78.

[image]

Comment: It looks like the easing property is working to me.  What aspect of easing isn't working?

Comment: Oooh I see Easing isn't deforming the mesh, unlike the other settings.

Comment: well, in the gif, you see Easing affecting the bone. that's it...it ONLY affects the bone. it doesn't affect the mesh like Curve XY Offsets or Scale. but on this youtube video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nQCo2AGRT6o, you can see it actually working. he's using 2.77.1 and i'm using 2.78. thanks! :]

Comment: Looks like a bug to me.  Maybe a dev can confirm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well it kind of works, as you can see in this Blend File here:

[image]

I say `kind of` because the limitation is that you have to set up the driver which he's using in the video. Looks like a dependency graph issue to me to be honest. This theory is backed up by two things:

- if you transform the controller bone, and cancel that transform using <kbd>Esc</kbd> the bendy bone does not jump back into its original state (that's a bad bad thing)
- if you run Blender from the command line using the  `--enable-new-depsgraph` switch, everything works totally fine, even **not** having drivers on the bone deforms the mesh as it should.

You could try having the controller bone in a separate armature object. That might help overcoming the dependency graph issue. Or simply run Blender with new depsgraph on as indicated before.